# User activity timeline

Tags: support, answers

Is there a timeline where users can see their answers based on dates?
If not, where's the appropriate place to propose this feature? Here?

Comment: Do you just mean a chronological list of your answers? You can see that in your profile

Answer (score 6):

The ['answers' tab on your user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=answers&sort=newest) does that:

[image]

---

Alternatively, if you want to filter on a certain period, go to the Search page and enter a query similar to this one: `user:me created:2016-01-01..2016-12-31 is:a` and click the 'newest' tab:

[image]